# fcitx doesn't work with chromium

Tags: linux

I used Archlinux + Slim + Openbox before, my fcitx runs correctly.

Recently, I replaced OpenBox with Awesome. After that, I can't use fcitx normally with chromium and leafpad.

However, it works well in terminal and opera.

I have tried some other tiling windows, such as Xmonad, Stumpwm, but the situation was same.

My .xinitrc file is as follows,

```
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
#fcitx
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx 
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx 
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"

fcitx &
exec awesome
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check screenshot in: http://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Configure_%28Other%29

If "fcitx" doesn't show up in the menu as screenshot, there must be something wrong with your install.

Make sure you have installed fcitx-gtk2.

If you have installed it, and it's still not in the menu, that might because a bug/limitation in pacman when you're doing upgrade, reinstall it to make sure the post-install script correctly.

Comment: Thanks, install both fcitx-gtk2 and fcitx-gtk3 fix it.